# using an alias adress for a job application

Tags: professionalism, resume, email

Some email providers allow you to 'tag' an email address by putting a `+` and something after it, and I often use this to sort my emails. If I were to put `myemail+comapanyName@example.com` instead of `myemail@example.com` on my CV could it come off as unprofessional or inappropriate?

Thanks

Comment: Two potential issues: 1. it might give off the impression that you're sending out lots of applications 2. it might cause (incorrectly implemented) automated application management systems' e-mail address validation checker to choke on the address (unlikely)

Comment: @pmf If someone is looking for a job, the HR folks know that 99% of the time the applicant is looking at multiple, *many*, opportunities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CV could it come off as unprofessional or inappropriate?

I don't see an issue with this at all, as a hiring manager I really only care about having **a reliable way to communicate with you**.  (*Especially with the format you have suggested, but any valid email format should be fine for any decent HR system*.)

The key here is to be sure its a standard email format.  Do not use special characters such *as the plus sign*.  You can do something like MonkeyJoe.CocaCola@example.com.  ( A period is safe to use )

There will always be some delicate snowflake that is offended by what you say or do, but I would not worry in this case.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Can you elaborate?  If I put on my resume MonkeyJoeCocaCola@example.com what is the issue or failure point as long as the email address is valid?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Its ok.  In almost all the modern human capital management systems, a period in the section befoe the @ symbol is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the application tracking system of the company you are applying for is an awful piece of legacy software.

This means, chances are good that their email validation logic exists but is broken enough to reject anything that's not `someone@somedomain.tld`, with:

- `someuser` being ASCII letters, digits, dots and dashes/underscores
- `somedomain` being pure ASCII (no IDN/punycode)
- `tld` being a classic top-level domain, i.e. 2 or 3 characters (country TLD or com/net/org). Maybe you are lucky and `info` is included as well since it's one of the first TLDs introduced later, but I surely would not use any of the new TLDs (`.foobar`, `.berlin`, etc.).

---

Of course, if you are applying at a smaller tech company, chances are good that they either don't use such a legacy system or the applications are processed by someone smart enough to realize the system is broken and your application is not worth throwing out because of this. But at a large company with thousands of applications and pure HR people processing them and putting them in the tracking system? "Oh, the email is invalid, delete"

I wouldn't risk it, at least not when applying to a company where I would *really* like to work.